# awk program check if there is '0' in each line

Tags: arrays, linux, unix, awk

Sample input:

```
a 54 65 43
b 45 12 98
c 99 0 12
d 3 23 0
```

Sample output:
`c,d`

Basically I want to check if there's a value of zero in each line, if yes, print the index(a,b,c,d).

My code:

`for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i==0){print$1}` I got a syntax error

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

another approach

```
$ awk '/\y0\y/{print $1}' file
c
d
```

`\y` is the word-boundary operator.  Might be only in `gawk`.

Answer (score 2):

The code needs a set of braces.

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==0) print $1}' filename
```

(The `print` *doesn't* need braces so I took those out.)

If the first field doesn't ever contain a number, maybe start the loop from 2.

The general form of an Awk script is a sequence of

```
condition { action }
```

pairs, where the latter needs braces around it. In the absence of a condition, an action is taken on each line, unconditionally.

Comment: I am writing in an `.awk` file so I did not include braces in the code.

Comment: You still need them.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem.. I thought the for loop was a condition instead of a command so I did not put the braces around it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To make your code work, you need change it to:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==0) print $1}' file
c                                                      
d
```

- You need to put the code inside a block (`{}` pair).
- You have to use `$i` instead of `i` in the if condition, `$i` means the `i`th column.
- Although it's not needed here, it's better to add a space between command and paramter. (`print $1`)

And it's better to improve it a little bit:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==0) {print $1;next}}' file
```

Add `next` to avoid `print $1` multiple times when there're more than one `0` in the line.

Given the columns are space separated, you can do it this way too:

```
awk '/( |^)0( |$)/{print $1}' file
```

This one does not require GNU awk.
`/( |^)0( |$)/` is a [RegEx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), and in the command it's short for `$0 ~ /( |^)0( |$)/`.
`^` means line beginnings, `$` line endings here.